# Building a war on intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, war

I have a Java EE project I have imported into IntelliJ . I can compile the project but for some reason not able to build a war artifact , when I go to the `build` tab the `<build artifacts>`  option is blanked out ( ie I cannot select it ) . my project compiles fine but I am still confused on how I could build my war .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Operating sequence can be such (dependent of IDE version):

Choose:

**File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts**

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and create new artifact:

[image]

After this actions item **Build artifacts** should be available.

Comment: No, Web Applications are only supported in Ultimate edition

Comment: not getting any output when going for Apply and then OK, is there something missing ..

Comment: @HelloIT You are wrong. In Intellij Idea CE you can easily build artifacts  such as JAR or WAR. For this purpoise go to the Project structure -> Artifacts. Press +, chose JAR. Add a folder WEB-INF, press Create MANIFEST. After all, in the menu choose Build -> Build artifacts. I tested it on the Intellij IDEA 2018.1.4 CE. Works fine

Comment: @YanPak can you describe better how to do it?

Comment: @Oximer yes. Next steps you have to do:
1) Open project structure (⌘; or File -> Project structure)
2) Press Artifacts on the left pane
3) Press on the + on the top of the second from left pane, and choose Jar -> From modules with dependencies
4) You will see on the main part of the dialog window your new <module-_name>.jar entity and <module_name> compile output folder
5) Create on the top level the next folders hierarchy: WEB-INF -> classes

Comment: 6) Move '<module_name> compile output' folder into new classes dir
7) Rename <module_name>.jar into <your desired name>.war, also you can change output directory and name of the artifact builder there 
8) That's all! Press Apply button, close dialog and Go to Build -> Build artifacts -> <your desired name artifact builder>
If compilation is Ok, you will find your war file in output directory.
Good luck, Oximer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the IntelliJ Community Edition with Gradle, try this:

1. Add the 'war' plugin to your build.gradle file:

   plugins {
   ...
   id("war")
   ...
   }
2. In your Gradle window, double click on [project]/Tasks/build/build

[image]

3. Your WAR file will be in build/libs folder:

[image]

source (and more detailed info):
https://www.zoftino.com/developing-kotlin-applications-using-intellij-idea-and-gradle