# How to create war file in IntelliJ Community Edition for a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, war

I want to develop a war file for my project in IntelliJ. In Eclipse, there is a option to export the project as war file. But I am unable to solve the same issue in IntelliJ.

Comment: just set the type in your pom.xml and run clean install

Comment: @ChanjungKim it's not about "importing" a war, it's about "creating a war"

Comment: Maybe possible answer: http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2014/02/generating-war-file-from-plain-intellij.html

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323908/building-a-war-on-intellij/19324086 There is explanation for community edition in the comments for answer

Comment: If you're using maven, you could do the following : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring initalize makes it easy to create.

[image]